# Data Store for API Request Response Log

Tags: mongodb, storage

What is the best store to persist following information

```
- Input HTTP Request Headers and JSON Payload received (before processing)
- Time of request
- Status (Authenticated, Validated, Processed etc)
- Response sent to caller (after processing)
```

Overall the goal is to persist input request before doing authentication, validation and processing. It is primarily for audit purpose but should allow index on certain fields extracted from payload as well as time, status etc. Another query pattern would be some range based queries on time, say for replaying requests in last 10 minutes because they would not be processed etc.

Solutions thought : Since input payload can be persisted as blob or in unstructured fashion, I was looking forward to store in document store like MongoDB. Another option considered was to store in MySQL where entire payload and response sent was stored as blob, barring few fields on which search is required.

Ref : https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/

PS : Some additional information

1. Payload size : Each request response should consume under 2KB
2. QPS of your system (very low) - Its high write low read system
3. Data : Its going to be huge, so probably sharded store will be required

Comment: Your datastore selection should depend on the following factors. 1. Payload size. 2. QPS of your system 3. Data growth rate. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Mongo or SQL for something like this. For time seres data, something like Cassandra or ElasticSearch will be easier at setting up a cluster, shard correctly, maintaining consistent write performance.

Comment: Moesif is off topic for this